# Python scikits learn - Separating Hyperplane equation

Tags: python, geometry, machine-learning, scikits, scikit-learn

A separating hyperplane's equation is `W.X + b = 0`.

For a [support vector machine in scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_separating_hyperplane.html#example-svm-plot-separating-hyperplane-py), how is the separating hyperplane derived? What do '`a`' and '`w`' signify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In scikit-learn `coef_` attribute holds the vectors of the separating hyperplanes for linear models. It has shape `(n_classes, n_features)` if `n_classes > 1` (multi-class one-vs-all) and `(1, n_features)` for binary classification.

In this toy binary classification example, `n_features == 2`, hence `w = coef_[0]` is the vector orthogonal to the hyperplane (the hyperplane is fully defined by it + the intercept).

To plot this hyperplane in the 2D case (any hyperplane of a 2D plane is a 1D line), we want to find a `f` as in `y = f(x) = a.x + b`. In this case `a` is the slope of the line and can be computed by `a = -w[0] / w[1]`.

Comment: Why is `a = -w[0] / w[1]` ?   And to find b, why do we compute `- (clf.intercept_[0]) / w[1]`. Shouldn't `b = clf.intercept_[0]`?

Comment: It's just a simple matter of switching to the generic n-dimensional parameterization of the hyperplane to the 2D-specific equation of a line `y = a.x + b`: the generic `w_0 x + w_1 y + w_3 = 0` can be rewritten `y = - (w_0 / w_1) x + (w_3 / w_1)`

Comment: s/switching to/switching from/

Comment: Also the final expression should be: `y = - (w_0 / w_1) x - (w_3 / w_1)` but stackoverflow does not allow to edit old comments.